# Hangouts API for Video Chat in Android device

Tags: android, voice, google-hangouts, videochat

I have to implement Voice/Video Chat Android Native App. Thought of  using Hangout API So gone through the below links. I am little confused,  I didn't understand how to do it in Native Android App. It looks like it is for Desktop Web Browser.

https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/getting-started

https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/running#running-private

https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/writing

**Is Current Hangout API's useful for Android Native App?**

Can anyone help me on

- Implementing Voice/Video Chat Using Hangout API in my Android Native App
- Any  Sample Apps (.apk) or Links available

Comment: Please someone help me. i have to start implementing Video/Voice chat.But till now i don't have clarity on where to start and how to implement . Can i do this with Hangout Apis ? Please help

Comment: No android-mantra...but now i am  not working on this.... I don't know how to close this ticket. Please help me